# How to scrape Poster, Genre, Runtime and Synopsis from IMDb using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

> I have this code that scrapes Ranking, Title, Rating, Year, and Cast. I want to implement the Poster/Image URL, Genre, Runtime, and Synopsis too. How can I do this following the logic below?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv

url = "http://www.imdb.com/chart/top"
response = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept-Language": "en"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
movies = soup.select("td.titleColumn")
crew = [a.attrs.get("title") for a in soup.select("td.titleColumn a")]
ratings = [
    b.attrs.get("data-value") for b in soup.select("td.posterColumn span[name=ir]")
]

list = []

for index in range(0, len(movies)):
    movie_string = movies[index].get_text()
    movie = " ".join(movie_string.split()).replace(".", "")
    movie_title = movie[len(str(index)) + 1 : -7]
    year = re.search("\((.*?)\)", movie_string).group(1)
    place = movie[: len(str(index)) - (len(movie))]

    data = {
        "place": place,
        "movie_title": movie_title,
        "rating": ratings[index],
        "year": year,
        "star_cast": crew[index],
    }
    list.append(data)

for movie in list:
    print(
        movie["place"],
        "-",
        movie["movie_title"],
        "(" + movie["year"] + ") -",
        "Starring:",
        movie["star_cast"],
        movie["rating"],
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.to_csv("top250movies.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Please update the question with your own attempt to reach the desired result and let us know where specifically you run into issues. See [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).
What you're asking is perfectly doable, but SO is not a free code writing service. Side note: don't call a list "list". `list` is a built-in data type in Python, which your code is overwriting. E.g. use `list_ = []` or something instead.

Comment: You will need to extract the hrefs from each title and go to them individually for your desired information. I can't find that information any where on the page (besides the post url, you can just get the url from the a element